# Why does Ext.form.ComboBox remove all the values automatically when selected any item in the list?

Tags: forms, extjs

I've made a combo box and its working fine except when I select one of the items in the combobox, it removes all other values in it. Here is a piece of code:

```
var comboitemarray = new Array();
for(var comboitems=0;comboitems<listitems.length;comboitems++){
    comboitemarray[comboitems] = listitems[comboitems].item;
}
dynamicformfield = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    id: fieldname,
    fieldLabel: fieldlabel,
    name: fieldname,
    editable: false,
    autoSelect : true,
    store: comboitemarray,
    queryMode: 'local',
});
```

Any idea? Or am I missing anything here?

Comment: Mind the excess *comma* after `queryMode: 'local',`.

Answer (score 0):

You gave an Array as store :

```
store: comboitemarray
```

Where it expects an Ext.data.Store. Implement an Ext.data.ArrayStore() from that comboitemarray array . Check the documentation of ArrayStore and always test in firebug for the errors.

Answer (score 0):

I behaves that way because it's not a select-box, it's a combo-box.

If you had the following items:

- a
- aa
- aaa

and you selected "aa", there would then be two options in the box: 'aa', and 'aaa'.

If you think carefully about how you'd like it to work, you'll realize that to get what you want will break ability to have any sort of meaningful type-ahead functionality.